# How did Rowena call Lucifer?

Tags: supernatural

In Season 11 Episode 9, we saw Rowena perform a spell that makes Lucifer's cage appear, and allow Sam to talk to Lucifer without entering the cage.

As far as I know, the only ways to open Lucifer's cage are breaking the 66 Seals, using the rings of the Horsemen, or probably Death. If by a spell in the Book of the Dammed could free Lucifer, what was the point of breaking the 66 Seals in Season 4? Azazel and Lilith could have very easily found the Book of the Dammed and used the spell to bring Lucifer out of his cage.

What exactly did Rowena's spell do? Did it remove Lucifer from his cage and put him in a temporary cage? If it temporarily brought the original cage, where was Michael? (He's supposed to trapped in the same cage with Lucifer.)

Comment: could it be that it was meant to be more like an image of him than his real form being brought out of the cage......thus only sort of an apparitatoin or how it is called?

Comment: @Thomas if it was just an image then how was he able to nullify the effects of the spell on cage and pull Sam into the cage? That cage was supposed to be secure because of the spell

Comment: Aht htat is something different with image I meant apparition....that is what the spell SHOULD have had as effect.......but the problem was for sam......the spell though did its work but the CAGE itself did no longer.

Comment: @Thomas so you mean that since the original cage was damaged so Lucifer was able to use his magic and pull Sam into the temp cage even though the spell was protecting the temp cage? Its kinda confusing. Shouldn't Lucifers magic be limited to the main cage and not to the cage in which his image is getting pulled into (if thats the truth)?

Comment: That is what I meant. Although not sure what the real explanation will be there

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer to this on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Supernatural-Why-wasnt-Michael-in-Lucifers-cage).  Apparently the cage we see is a temporary "holding cell" to hold Lucifer while Sam talks to him.

Not sure why Azazel and Lilith didn't use this - maybe the spell and the "holding cell" are two parts of a whole? (i.e., the spell only moves the target to the holding cell and back).

Per the Quora article: (paraphrasing below)
Before Lucifer gets summoned, he asks Rowena if she's sure she can do this without opening the Cage - this seems to lend credence to the idea that this is not the Cage itself, but a temporary holding area.  Although the Cage was, apparently, damaged when the Darkness descended, it was not enough for Lucifer to leave physically under his own power.

Comment: What are Quora's sources for this? What are their reasonings?

Comment: Edited to show more of the Quora information